# PHP MySQL Giving Me 'Array to String Conversion Error' When I'm clearly giving a single entry in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, type-conversion

So here is the error that I'm getting in my browser:
[image: Apparently my SQL query has a variable array in it...]

Here is my code, including line 158:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($sortbyperiod); $i++) {
    $queryname = "SELECT name FROM '" . $sortbyperiod[$i] . "' ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, day ASC";
    $result = $con_classdata->query($queryname);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $names = $row['name'];
```

The variable $sortbyperiod[$i] is clearly a single entry. Why is it giving me an array?

EDIT: Please do not give me PDO solutions, I prefer using mysqli.
EDIT 2: Text code instead of image.

Comment: 1. Posting code as image is discouraged. 2. Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you 100.000% certain that `$sortbyperiod` is not an array of arrays.  If it is an array of arrays, then `$sortbyperiod[$i]` would be an array and so would result in that error message.  Could you do `print_r($sortbyarray);` to see what it gives?

Comment: Shoot, completely forgot about that. Code is way too long. Thanks

Comment: If you do a var_dump() of $sortbyperiod what do you get?